# How to distribute a RAD C++ project?

Tags: c++, runtime, c++builder, rad

I am finishing my current c++ project. Just want to try running its exe file on another PC BEFORE generating a setup. I realised there is no runtime kit for Embarcadero C++. I just wondering how can I simply do the similar thing to complete its runtime environment.
(direct run of exe popped "rtl190.bpl missing")

p.s. I found a Redist folder under: Embarcadero/RAD studio/12.0/ where can I copy them to the target PC?

Answer:  Many thanks to Matt McNabb. I tried those two options in Project menu of RAD. It worked!. The file size increased， all lib links were included. I took screenshots for setting location. But I don't have the reputation to post.. what a shame.

Comment: There is a menu option "Project > Deployment" . I haven't figured out how the actual connecting to a Deployment Server works; however this window will actually list the runtime dependencies.

Comment: The question appears to be about primary distribution of your software, not redistribution of part of C++Builder per se. This question is very specific to that product.

Comment: BTW my advice would be to build with "Use dynamic RTL"=False and "Use runtime packages"=False. For the measly price of a large .exe file, you eliminate deployment issues in one fell swoop.

Comment: Since it took me so long to find this on XE3, I'll add that the Use dynamic RTL"=False is under the C++ Linker Options and the Use runtime packages"=False is under the Runtime Packages Options.